# Is the chi squared goodness of fit test valid for the multinomial distribution if the outcomes are unlabeled?

Tags: statistics, dice, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

I'm investigating Sketchy Dice Inc. for purportedly selling unfair dice with the following probability distribution:

\begin{align}
p(1)&=0.1 \\
p(2)&=0.3 \\
p(3)&= 0.2 \\
p(4)&= 0.15 \\
p(5)&= 0.15 \\
p(6)&= 0.1
\end{align}

In order to obfuscate their villainy, Sketchy Dice Inc. has removed the numbers from the faces of all the dice shortly before a police raid.

I was given one dice and asked to determine whether we can say it does not have the above distribution. Let's say you roll the dice 100 times. If the faces were labelled you could simply do a standard chi squared test using the statistic:

\begin{equation}
\chi^2 = \frac{\left(O_i-E_i\right)^2}{E_i}
\end{equation}

and compare to the chi squared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom. Here $E_i = 100 p(i)$ is the number of times we expect to roll $i$ given a dice made by Sketchy Dice Inc and $O_i$ is the number of times $i$ is actually rolled. However, with the faces scrubbed, what can we do? My first inclination would be to sort $E_i$ and $O_i$ before performing the calculation, but it is no longer clear that this loss of labeling information does not invalidate the test.

How does a lack of correct labeling information impact this statistical test, to what extent is it still valid, and if it is completely unworkable, is there any viable alternative? Let's say we aren't being paid to roll dice and don't want to rely on being able to produce more than one observation of 100 rolls.

Note: I know I could alternatively test if the dice is unfair in general, but that's not what I'm asking. The above distribution is particularly heinous and making such a die would merit a higher prison sentence than just making an unfair die.

Comment: Not following.  What's stopping you from labelling the faces?  Sure, you won't get them right, but at least you can keep track.  If you can't keep track of which faces have come up, I don't think you have much hope here.

Comment: @lulu I would undoubtedly have to label the faces to count frequencies. The issue is this: Let's say I label some side of the die 1. If that side was labeled 2 before it was scrubbed, then I will almost certainly not detect that the die has the given distribution. I might take the sample and then say "Hey, the side I labeled 1 comes up about 30% of the time, I wonder if it was originally labeled 2" But it seems like that process of relabeling adds extra uncertainty which must be accounted for. This additional uncertainty may invalidate the $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: You don't need to get the original distribution exactly...all you need to show is that it isn't fair.  Just look at the distribution of the max.  One of your faces will come up about a third of the time.  Just roll often enough to rule that out (statistically).

Comment: That's not good enough. I need to know if I can rule out this distribution in particular. See the last comment in my question. Maybe 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05 is not illegal.

Comment: I don't see anyway to detect this particular distribution.

Comment: But if the sides of the dice were never relabeled there is a way to detect the distribution. It's standard. That's the whole crux of the question.

Comment: If my coin is weighed to come up $H$ with probability $.75$ but I've scraped off the faces,  you can't distinguish it from a coin for which $T$ comes up with probability $.75$

Comment: Right, my comments were less precise than the statement in the actual question. I don't want to "detect" this distribution. I want to "rule it out". I would fail to rule out the 0.75 T coin. But I could easily say that a fair coin, 10/90 coin, or a 90/10 coin is not 75/25 heads--even if the faces are scratched off.

Comment: I don't think this is very precise. It's easy to rule this out by looking at the distribution of the max or min, as I said.  As for the values in the middle...well, distinguishing $.15$ from the fair value of $.167$ is going to be *very* hard work.  Anyway, I think I am missing your point here, and I doubt my comments are helpful.  Sorry about that, and good luck!